# Hit a button on Android and takes a long response time

Tags: android, button, touch, response

First, I use a System.Out.print to output something but I don't see that in the console or logcat, where does it display?

Then when hit the button, it takes long time to respond. I log the files from logcat and have No idea what the OS is doing behind which took so long.

```
  02-16 13:01:07.859: WARN/WindowManager(51): Key dispatching timed out sending to      com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity
 02-16 13:01:08.101: WARN/WindowManager(51): Dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=4     repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to Window{44dcd868       com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.MyAccount1_1Activity paused=false} @ 1329425383564 
 lw=Window{44dcd868 com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.MyAccount1_1Activity  paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@44e756f0 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false    fp=false mcf=Window{44e2b0a0 com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.games.slotMachine paused=false}}}
  02-16 13:01:08.119: WARN/WindowManager(51): Current state:  {{null to Window{44e2c788 com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity paused=false} @ 1329426068120 lw=Window{44e2c788 com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@44e2c5a0 fin=true gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{44e2b0a0 com.test.finalapp/com.test.finalapp.games.slotMachine paused=false}}}
02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51): ANR in process: com.test.finalapp (last in com.test.finalapp)
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Annotation: keyDispatchingTimedOut
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51): CPU usage:
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Load: 0.37 / 0.37 / 0.38
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51): CPU usage from 8216ms to 81ms ago:
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51):   system_server: 4% = 3% user + 1% kernel / faults: 4 minor
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51):   obango.finalapp: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
 02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
02-16 13:01:08.240: INFO/ActivityManager(51): TOTAL: 5% = 4% user + 1% kernel
02-16 13:01:08.251: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Removing old ANR trace file from /data/anr/traces.txt
 02-16 13:01:09.081: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 239 SIG: 3
 02-16 13:01:09.239: INFO/dalvikvm(239): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:09.458: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 51 SIG: 3
 02-16 13:01:09.486: INFO/dalvikvm(51): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:10.457: INFO/dalvikvm(239): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:12.037: INFO/dalvikvm(51): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:12.055: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 223 SIG: 3
  02-16 13:01:12.269: INFO/dalvikvm(223): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:12.358: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 213 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:12.375: INFO/dalvikvm(213): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-16 13:01:12.608: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 154 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:12.885: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 146 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:12.905: INFO/dalvikvm(213): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:13.113: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 189 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:13.348: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 181 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:13.602: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 170 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:13.816: INFO/dalvikvm(146): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-16 13:01:13.976: INFO/dalvikvm(189): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-16 13:01:14.084: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 103 SIG: 3
  02-16 13:01:14.144: INFO/dalvikvm(103): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:14.342: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 106 SIG: 3
02-16 13:01:16.950: INFO/dalvikvm(170): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:18.814: INFO/dalvikvm(181): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:23.204: WARN/MediaPlayer(239): info/warning (1, 44)
 02-16 13:01:23.578: DEBUG/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
 02-16 13:01:24.137: WARN/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 76 msecs, 2 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
 02-16 13:01:24.385: DEBUG/dalvikvm(239): GC freed 4564 objects / 281416 bytes in 77ms
 02-16 13:01:24.914: INFO/MediaPlayer(239): Info (1,44)
 02-16 13:01:25.537: INFO/dalvikvm(106): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 02-16 13:01:26.370: INFO/dalvikvm(103): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:26.435: INFO/dalvikvm(223): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:27.350: INFO/dalvikvm(170): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:27.611: INFO/dalvikvm(181): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:28.074: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.test.finalapp/.Leaderboard1 (has extras) }
 02-16 13:01:28.934: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Displayed activity com.test.finalapp/.Leaderboard1: 754 ms (total 754 ms)
 02-16 13:01:29.889: INFO/dalvikvm(189): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:30.152: INFO/dalvikvm(146): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:30.375: INFO/dalvikvm(154): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 02-16 13:01:31.183: INFO/dalvikvm(106): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: seems like your activity FeaturedActivity is facing ANR (Application Not Responding).

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to use System.out.print?

Comment: mix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mix);
  mix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {  Random randomgen=new Random();
              
              float probability=randomgen.nextFloat();
              System.out.print("the random gen probability is   "); 
              System.out.print(probability); });

Comment: When I hit the mix button it takes a long time, and I checked the logcat and above shown.

Comment: So you're trying to print the probability on device's screen?

Comment: Actually the hitting of the button aleady beyond the FeaturedActivity. FeatureActivity-->Game--->hit button.     Its already inside the game.

Answer (score 1):

You should give us the code that is executed and, if you just call a method, give us the code of the method, too. Yous system.out will be printed in the logcat, just check for the tag `System`.

Even without your code, I can start a educated guess: Your button probably trigger a long taking operation and blocks the UI thread as the touchlistener runs on the UI Thread.
You should also consider moving it into an AsyncTask that is meant to be used for long term operations like internet access or calculations. You can update your UI easily from the AsyncTask, too.

Comment: My button implementation is very straightforward, just mix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mix); mix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { }).

Comment: It is not the question how you implemented the OnClickListener, it is more important what is executed in the onClick. As I see in a comment you just generate a random value and print it. That shouldn't take long. So my question is: Do you really think that the button takes long or is your complete application "slow"? Also please specify what "takes long time" means. 1 minute? 1 second?